# NotificationCenter Delphi, Exception under MacOS

Tags: delphi

I have played around with the NotificationCenter in Delphi.

That is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.BT_NotifyClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Note: TNotification;
begin
  Note := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification;
  try
    try
      Note.Name := 'Test-Note';
      Note.Title := 'Test-Notification';
      Note.AlertBody := 'Notification zum Testen!';
      Note.FireDate := Now;
      NotificationCenter1.PresentNotification(Note);
    except
      on E: ELocalNotificationAccess do
        ShowMessage('Eine Exception vom Typ ' + E.ClassName + ' ist aufgetreten! ' + E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    Note.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It works fine with Windows 10, but when I try it on MacOS (10.15), I get an exception of the type “ELocalNotificationAccess”. Additionally it says something like that the user prohibited the access to the NotificationCenter.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Comment: Sorry, it's 10.4

Comment: For some reason or another, the app is not being signed correctly (possibly a macOS issue). In Project Options, Deployment > Provisioning, please fill out the "Apple or Mac Development Certificate" edit with your Mac certificate details, e.g.: Apple Development: David Nottage (A1234BCSR). (not my real details)

Comment: I was no able to test your solution yet, but thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I tested it and it works. Thank you!